Is there a connected graph where every vertex has degree k >1 with no Hamiltonian cycle?
I am trying to construct a simple connected graph where every single node has the same degree $k>1$ but without containing any Hamiltonian cycle.
Take this simple example as shown in the images below.

The graph on the left has a Hamiltonian cycle (shown in blue) but every node has degree $3$. On the other hand, when I remove edges $FC$ and $BD$ there's no longer any Hamiltonian cycle as you can see on the graph on the right but nodes $F,B,C,D$ all have degree $2$.
Does there exist a connected graph that has every vertex with the same degree $k>1$ without containing any Hamiltonian cycle? A proof or counterexample will be appreciated.

I guess the graph must be connected. What about the Petersen-Graph ?

The graph must be connected indeed. The Petersen graph seems to have a Hamiltonian path but no Hamiltonian cycle.

The graphs above don't satisfy the conditions I'm looking for. I want a graph that satisfies two conditions: 1) every vertex must have the same degree and 2) the graph cannot have any hamiltonian cycle. The examples above either satisfy one condition or the other.

OK, I overlooked "same degree"

@JCr What's your objection to the Petersen graph, then?

You're right. I've just realised. My apologies.

By the way, the term for a graph where every vertex has the same degree is a "regular graph". This might help search for more counterexamples (link).

A good place to search for counterexamples is https://houseofgraphs.org/, which has both "regular" "Hamiltonian", and "connected" as parameters you can require/exclude, as well as more filters such as the number of vertices and edges.
